# JQuery 'animate' stops working after 2 calls

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some very simple jquery that moves a `<div>` (a box) left and right when the relevant button is clicked. However, after one or 2 clicks, the `<div>` stops moving:

What's going on?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn1").click(function() {
    $("#box").animate({
      right: "100px"
    });
  });
  
  $("#btn2").click(function() {
    $("#box").animate({
      left: "100px"
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<button id="btn1">Animate right</button>
<button id="btn2">Animate left</button>
<div id="box" style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;margin:6px;position:relative;"></div>
```

Comment: You’re just setting the CSS `left` property with one click and the CSS `right` property with the other. You never actually change them again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you never reset the `right` or `left` values back to their default. You can achieve that using `css()`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn1").click(function() {
    $("#box").animate({
      right: "100px"
    }).css('left', 'auto');
  });

  $("#btn2").click(function() {
    $("#box").animate({
      left: "100px"
    }).css('right', 'auto')
  });
});
```

```css
#box {
  background: #98bf21;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 6px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<button id="btn1">Animate right</button>
<button id="btn2">Animate left</button>
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks - pretty new to this.

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Comment: OK - also got it working using `right: "+=100"` to move one way and right: "`-+100`" to move the other. I tried `right: "+=100"` and `left: "=100"` which didn't work presumably because im trying to set the left a right properties at the same time?

Comment: Yep, that's another way to do it, but note that a fundamental difference there is that the button clicks would cumulatively change the position. Right now it only moves once no matter how many times you click the button.

Comment: Yep thanks Rory - that was sort of what I was originally expecting - that each click would move it further because `animate right` would animate BY a specific amount whereas I think I understand now that it's actually animating the div TO a specific value of it's left or right property.